# Check Unique Chars in A String

Tags: java, strings, comparative-review

Two solutions to check if a String contains unique characters.
Wanted to know if these solutions can be optimized further.

The Code:

```
 public class UniqueCharactersInString {


        //running time O(N) and O(N) space
        public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String text) {

            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            //only one char has to be unique
            if (text.length() == 1) {
                return true;
            }

            HashSet<Character> textChars = new HashSet<>();

            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                if (textChars.contains(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
                textChars.add(c);
            }
            return true;
        }


        //running time O(N ^ 2) and O(1) space

        public static boolean hasUniqueChars2(String text) {

            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
             return false;
            }

            //only one char has to be unique
            if (text.length() == 1) {
             return true;
            }
            //nested loop to check
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; i < text.length(); j++) {
                    if (i != j && text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(j)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        public static void main(String... args) {

            System.out.println(hasUniqueChars("test123"));
            System.out.println(hasUniqueChars2("test123"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Both solutions

Both your solutions check for `text.lenght() == 1`. This is not really much of an optimization and it makes it seem like it is a special case, but your code will do just fine without that check. Remove it.

### First solution

Your first solution using a HashSet can be improved by using the return value of the `add(...)` method, which is `true` if the value is added, and `false` if the value was already there. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))

This allows you to simplify the inner condition from:

> ```
>             if (textChars.contains(c)) {
>                 return false;
>             }
>             textChars.add(c);
> ```

to

```
            if (!textChars.add(c)) {
                return false;
            }
```

In general, while your complexity assessments are accurate, there is a significant amount of space involved in converting `char` to `Character` instances and then the overheads of the `HashSet` are significant. I imagine for even reasonably large strings, it will be slower than your second option... which also has problems.

### Second solution

This solution is neatly written, but has a significant performance issue. Instead of the `j` loop running from `0` to `text.length()` it can instead run from `0` to `i`. The solution you currently have compares many values redundantly (for example, in the word `hello` it will compare `h` to `e` and also `e` to `h`)

The resulting code would look like:

```
        //nested loop to check
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

### Bug

While answering this section, though, I see your code actually has a bug, which irritates me, because this has to be something you have seen..... your code's `j` loop looks like:

> ```
> for (int j = 0; i < text.length(); j++) {
> ```

and that contains the condition `i < text.lenght()` instead of `j < text.lenght()`.... so you have an infinite loop. Your code is broken. If you had run this code, you would know that....

### My recommendation

... is for a 3rd option to try. You should get the characters in an array, and then sort them, and compare neighbours....

for example:

```
    //running time O(N log(N)) and O(N) space
    public static boolean hasUniqueChars3(String text) {

        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
         return false;
        }

        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (chars[i] == chars[i - 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your comments and recommendation! I have fixed the bug and updated the review..I had run the second option for a false case only and did not notice it!